# How to get an google app script alert response to run different function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've gotten my EmailPDF script to run correctly.  But what I want is an alert to popup asking if you want to send the report.

```
function responseToSend() {
   var spreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
   var se = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   var prompt = ui.alert('Are you sure you wand to send this daily to ' + se + ' ?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)

    if(prompt == ui.Button.YES){(EmailPDF)
    }
     else{
       ui.alert('Permission denied.');
    }
```

}

```
function EmailPDF() { 

  var spreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var se = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
```

I first tried to write the ui.alert in my EmailPDF function.  But I couldn't get it to work.  I was able to get it to work if the response answer was YES, but when I would click NO it would still run the script. (i.e send the email)

I don't know what to up after "else {}" to get the script to stop running or return to the beginning.

Then I thought maybe I should create a function (responseToSend) that just runs the ui.alert and if the response is "yes" then run the EmailPDF function.

I'm sure it can be done both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function responseToSend() {
  var spreadSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var se = s.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ps = Utilities.formatString('Are you sure you want send this daily to %s ?',se);
  var prompt = ui.prompt(ps,ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(prompt.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES){
    EmailPDF();
  }else{
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
  }
}
```